Did Nina and Victor have a romantic connection or was it just built in his head?
Nabokovs Dozen, the short story 'Spring in Fialta'. The narrator is seemingly unreliable and usually the romantic parts are just his own interpretation of the event rather than her actual demeanor, which makes me believe that this relationship is one sided. But I would like to hear other's thoughts on it.

What exactly do you mean by usually the romantic parts are just his own interpretation of the event? Could you give an example of a romantic part which is clearly just his own interpretation? Or did you mean to say possibly and not usually?
